# java regex support for non-ascii values?

Tags: java, regex

We have a current method which clears out chars that are not alphabetic or whitespace which is simply

```
String clean(String input)
{
   return input==null?"":input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]","");
}
```

which really ought to be fixed to support non-english chars (e.g. ś,ũ, ... ). Unfortunately the java regex classes (e.g. 
    "\W" -A non-word character,
      "\p{Alpha}" -US-ASCII only}.  ) don't seem to support this. Is there a way of doing this with java regex rather than looping manually though each character to test it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 6 Pattern handles Unicode, see [this doc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

> Unicode escape sequences such as
>   \u2014 in Java source code are
>   processed as described in §3.3  of the
>   Java Language Specification. Such
>   escape sequences are also implemented
>   directly by the regular-expression
>   parser so that Unicode escapes can be
>   used in expressions that are read from
>   files or from the keyboard. Thus the
>   strings "\u2014" and "\\u2014", while
>   not equal, compile into the same
>   pattern, which matches the character
>   with hexadecimal value 0x2014.
>
> Unicode blocks and categories are
>   written with the \p and \P constructs
>   as in Perl. \p{prop} matches if the
>   input has the property prop, while
>   \P{prop} does not match if the input
>   has that property. Blocks are
>   specified with the prefix In, as in
>   InMongolian. Categories may be
>   specified with the optional prefix Is:
>   Both \p{L} and \p{IsL} denote the
>   category of Unicode letters. Blocks
>   and categories can be used both inside
>   and outside of a character class.