# POSIX character equivalents in Java regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, posix-ere, character-properties

I would like to use a regular expression like this in Java : `[[=a=][=e=][=i=]]`.

But Java doesn't support the POSIX classes `[=a=], [=e=] etc`.

How can I do this? More precisely, is there a way to not use US-ASCII?

Comment: Please do not add third-party stat trackers to your posts. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Java does support [posix character classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). The syntax is just different, for instance:

```
\p{Lower}
\p{Upper}
\p{ASCII}
\p{Alpha}
\p{Digit}
\p{Alnum}
\p{Punct}
\p{Graph}
\p{Print}
\p{Blank}
\p{Cntrl}
\p{XDigit}
\p{Space}
```

Comment: US ASCII only. Is there a way to use some locale ?

Comment: @Stephan, unfortunately no way that I know of. You can always match [unicode characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917774/java-regex-support-for-non-ascii-values) manually though to create your own character groups.

Answer (score 6):

Quoting from http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

> **POSIX character classes (US-ASCII only)**

```
\p{Lower}   A lower-case alphabetic character: [a-z]
\p{Upper}   An upper-case alphabetic character:[A-Z]
\p{ASCII}   All ASCII:[\x00-\x7F]
\p{Alpha}   An alphabetic character:[\p{Lower}\p{Upper}]
\p{Digit}   A decimal digit: [0-9]
\p{Alnum}   An alphanumeric character:[\p{Alpha}\p{Digit}]
\p{Punct}   Punctuation: One of !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
\p{Graph}   A visible character: [\p{Alnum}\p{Punct}]
\p{Print}   A printable character: [\p{Graph}\x20]
\p{Blank}   A space or a tab: [ \t]
\p{Cntrl}   A control character: [\x00-\x1F\x7F]
\p{XDigit}  A hexadecimal digit: [0-9a-fA-F]
\p{Space}   A whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]
```

Comment: I think POSIX also allows only ASCII, am I wrong? That must be a side note for users expecting posix to handle unicode.

Comment: On Oracle, they have implemented their regex flavor by following POSIX spec. They accept the special class [= =]. I didn't verify if the class adpats for the various locales Oracle supports though.

Comment: The posix specification does support different locales with *collation equivalence classes* described under point seven of the Posix Specification for Regular Expressions: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05

Answer (score 2):

Copied from [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)

> Java does not support POSIX bracket
>   expressions, but does support POSIX
>   character classes using the \p
>   operator. Though the \p syntax is
>   borrowed from the syntax for Unicode
>   properties, the POSIX classes in Java
>   only match ASCII characters as
>   indicated below. The class names are
>   case sensitive. Unlike the POSIX
>   syntax which can only be used inside a
>   bracket expression, Java's \p can be
>   used inside and outside bracket
>   expressions.

Comment: Tks for prompt reply, but is there a way to use some locale ?