# How to match all words in a sentence with scala combinators?

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

For a first test with scala combinators, I am trying to get all words from a sentence, but I am just getting "None" from the following code :

```
import java.io.File
import scala.io.Source
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

object PgnReader extends TagParser {

  def parseFile(inputFile:File) = {
    val pgnStream = Source.fromFile(inputFile)
    val pgnStr = pgnStream.mkString
    println(parseAll(tag, "Hello World !").getOrElse("None"))
    pgnStream.close
  }
}

trait TagParser extends RegexParsers {
  val tag:Parser[String] = """[:alpha:]+""".r ^^ (_.toString)
}
```

I would like to get something like :

```
Hello
World
```

or even like :

```
List(Hello, World)
```

Am I on the right way with my code ?

I am using scala 2.11 and [scala combinators](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might get you closer:

```
trait TagParser extends RegexParsers {
  val tag = rep("""\p{Alpha}+""".r) ^^ (_.map(_.toString))
}
```

POSIX character classes have a different syntax in Scala [(as inherited from Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612870/posix-character-equivalents-in-java-regular-expressions).  The `rep()` syntax allows for multiple occurrences (giving a `List()`).

That will still choke on the exclamation point, so you can augment your regex a little.  I'd probably also go with the notion of "tag" and "tags" separately to make things clearer:

```
trait TagParser extends RegexParsers {
  val tags = rep(tag)
  val tag = """\p{Alpha}+|!""".r ^^ (_.toString)
}
...
println(parseAll(tags, "Hello World !").getOrElse(None))
...
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use something like that to match sequence of tokens instead of one token:

```
trait TagParser extends RegexParsers {
  val tags: Parser[List[String]] = rep("""[a-zA-Z]+""".r)
}
```

`rep` is:

> A parser generator for repetitions.
>
> rep(p) repeatedly uses p to parse the input until p fails (the result
>   is a List of the consecutive results of p).

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/parser-combinators/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

Comment: Sorry, but I still get "none"

Comment: maybe because "!" doesn't match to [:alpha:] ?

Comment: No, still get none even without extra characters

Comment: use [a-zA-Z] instead of [:alpha:]

Comment: Excellent ! I should have though that [:alpha:] is not recognized everywhere. Thanks

Comment: you're welcome! this may help if you want to ignore some symbols: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925434/how-to-ignore-single-line-comments-in-a-parser-combinator